# Firestore data model that can filter by 'not contains' or similar

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

We have a list of `restaurant` with `ratings`. We are trying to find a `Data model` on `firestore` that would let us display to the user the list of those restaurants *where the user hasn't voted yet ordered by rating*.

The problem is that Firestore doesn't allow inequalities so it seems very hard to find a data model that would fit this use case.

We thought about a data model like this:

```
[restaurant]
 - id
 - rating

[user/id/votes]:
 - restaurant-id
```

But with this there is no way of doing the request we want. We tried adding a map on restaurants with `votes` and tried to filter by false, but it didn't work neither, only when filtering by true.

We looked into firestore because the rest of the app is based on firebase, but if this request isn't possible we will have to go into RDBMS.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159028/firebase-firestore-structure-for-getting-un-seen-trending-posts-social/53171545)** out but instead of using posts, use restaurants.

Comment: @AlexMamo The solution in that answer says to make 2 calls to see if it has been seen. Fair enough. But what if the first 30 posts have been seen ? Then you need 60 calls, 60 back and forth ?! The limit seems to be the sky

Comment: @Ced In that solution, there is only a single extra database call, to check if a particular post has been seen or not. If the OP thinks that in his app, a single restaurant cannot be viewd by as many users that a document can hold, then he can just simply use arrays.