# How to query a document and sub-document together Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My data structure looks something like this:

```
- posts (collection)
  - post (document)
      title
      description
      labels
      vote counts
      author
      author choice
      - votes (collection)
         - vote (document)
            choice
```

I need to write a query so that I find a post under the collections document where author != the user's UID, author choice == null, and category == any of some values (that I have no trouble with) but also where a document with the user's UID doesn't exist in the votes sub-collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries can only filter on values in the documents that they return. There is no way to have a condition on documents from a subcollection of those documents.

My preferred solution is to include information about the existence of the UIDs that exist in the `votes` subcollection in the parent document too, update that with every vote that is written, and then query on that new field.

---

Firestore queries also can only query on values that are present in a document. Values that don't exist are not in any index, so can't be part of a query condition.

That is tricky here as you want to test for the absence of a value. I also suspect that your list of UIDs is dynamic, so you'd have to update every parent document whenever a user is added.

So alternatively, you will have to retrieve the documents regardless of the existence in `votes` and then perform the additional filtering in your application code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wouldn’t storing the votes in the parent document scale poorly as that data would need to be read regardless of whether it’s needed or not? I think i’ll have to fetch the data regardless and filter the docs in a cloud function or on the client side if that’s the case.